# How do I only update the java runtime in a project?

Tags: java

I won't have much expertise in this so I apologize in advance. Basically I have a dropwizard application (using IntelliJ) that uses Java 8 compile time and runtime.

I want to still have Java 8 compile-time, but want to upgrade to Java 11 for run-time.

Someone told me it's possible but it's sort of confusing to me. I downloaded the zip file from https://jdk.java.net/11/ and changed my JAVA_HOME env variable on my windows machine. But won't this also change my project to compile in Java 11? How does Java 8 compatibility work?

Comment: Too broad to answer without knowing how you compile your code. Are you using an IDE? If so, which one? Are you using Ant? Maven? Gradle? Something else? All of them support explicitly specifying which Java version to compile with.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and Gradle